# Switching between databases in C# winforms

Tags: c#, sql, database

I made an application that generates reports based on data from a database.

The functionality of my application is correct, but I have a following problem: my client has 2 identical databases - one for testing and one for actual work he does.

My application should work with both databases (it should have a "switching mechanism"), but I don't know how to implement it.

I know that I could just switch between connection strings but the problem is that in my reports I use datasets that are bound to one database.

Is it possible to fill those datasets with the data from both databases (since the databases are identical in schema, it should be possible), and how would that be done, or do I have to use duplicate dataset/report pairs?

I'm using C# in VS 2010 with SQL Server 2005, and .rdlc for my reports. 
Thanks.

Comment: At what time do you want the switching to happen? Is it conditional?

Comment: The application has 2 forms - Login and the main form. The Login form contains a comboBox in which the user can choose which database he wants to use. So the switching should be done at that point (comboBox's item change). After that the user enters his user name and password and the application checks if the user has clearance to view these database(s)

Comment: If you need access control too to the database(s) based on credentials, then in addition to Ranhiru's answer, you need to keep a mapping between userid and key for connection string in app.config so that you can authorize the user.

Comment: I solved the authorization part, that works fine, and I managed to change the connection string in app.config as Ranhiru suggested (in design time), now I just need to make a function that changes it during run-time, and that should be it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you should should be able to change the connection string in one place and it should affect project-wide.

This will work ONLY IF you get the connection string from one place. Keep it in the `app.config` file.

See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to see how you can store and read the connection string from the app.config file.

Comment: It won't be `web.config` as it's a desktop application, but `app.config`.

Answer (score 0):

You've hit upon the reason why people implement the Repository pattern or at least a version of it.

You really need to remove your business logic away from the database, so that it is database agnostic. It shouldn't care where the data comes from only what it is.

From what you' said the implication is that your client doesn't wants more than just a change in the app.config connection string used for database access.

If that is so then, I know that it will entail some work, your best bet is to have a singleton pattern type class to control all data access to and from your data layer.

Using a known inteface you can use a factory pattern to create access to your development or live database at runtime (perhaps based on an app.config setting or even a test class that has no database access at all, but just returns hard coded test data.

Comment: Thanks for deleting it Lasse - I hadn't finished typing it.